# Three.js cannot see segments on plane

Tags: three.js

I simply created a plane and added it in my three.js scene but i cant see the plane segments.
Somebody know how can i do?

```
    var tergeo= new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100, 2, 2);
    var termat= new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xB4D159, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
    var terplane= new THREE.Mesh(tergeo, termat);
    scene.add(terplane);
```

Comment: Any chances to demonstrate the issue with a live example? Use the following fiddle (I've already added your plane mesh) https://jsfiddle.net/fch8mugx/

Comment: yes, its exactly that... why i cant see  segments?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean with segments. Do you mind posting a screenshot of the expected result?

Comment: PlaneGeometry(width : Float, height : Float, widthSegments : Integer, heightSegments : Integer)... in the live example on documentation if i change second or third params i can see segments dividing the plane... am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: https://threejs.org/docs/scenes/geometry-browser.html#PlaneGeometry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I simply created a plane and added it in my three.js scene but i cant see the plane segments.

The plane segments are not visible if you just use the plane geometry like in your code snippet. However, if you visualize the geometry via [WireframeGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/WireframeGeometry), you will see the expected result. `WireframeGeometry` is also use by the geometry browser from the official documentation.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.z = 2;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var tergeo= new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1, 2, 2);
    var termat= new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xB4D159, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
    var terplane= new THREE.Mesh(tergeo, termat);
    scene.add(terplane);
  
    var wireframegeo = new THREE.WireframeGeometry( tergeo );
    var wireframemat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial();
    var wireframe = new THREE.Line( wireframegeo, wireframemat );
    scene.add( wireframe );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
canvas {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/build/three.js"></script>
```